# How to override user_picture per comment?

Tags: theming, 8

I use the facebook connect plugin. By default it downloads the 50x50 pixel facebook image. It luckily stores it as the profile ID, which I can in turn use to look up the large version of the image. So I need way to:

1. Get the current user_picture for a comment, and then
2. Override it with a new url.

I have this so far:

```
function capewinefarms_preprocess_comment(&$variables) 
{
    $comment = $variables['elements']['#comment'];
    $variables['comment_create_date'] = format_date($comment->created->value, "custom", "d M Y, H:i:s");

    $variables['user_picture'] =  'BLA';
}
```

The above code replaces the user's profile pic with the words "BLA". But I don't want that. So I need a way to see what the variables object looks like, so I can see where to get the current value and to change it. But if I do this:

```
print_r($variables);
```

It just bombs out and shows a blank screen (as if the variable is blank).

How do I change the user picture?

Answer (score 0):

A dump of the `$variables` array is probably causing out-of-memory problems as preprocess variables in D8 can have some heavy depth to them.

Anyway, you can retrieve the image url from `$user_picture` render array which has a reference to the comment's user:

```
  $comment_user = $variables['user_picture']['#user'];
  if ($user_image = $comment_user->user_picture->first()) {
    $user_image_uri = $user_image->entity->uri->value;
  }
```